# WindowsForms auto generated a class, how do I separate that out into its own namespace?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form application in the namespace TestUI, it has a customer class, instantiated as below:

```
    List<Customer> cl = db.Customers.ToList();
```

But `Customer` points to an auto-generated class file in the same namespace `TestUI.Customer`. I have created a new class  `DataLayerTest.Customer` but I dont know how to make the original reference this class.

I have tried adding a `using` statement to the top of the file, and whilst I can reference it if I rename it I cant access it in place of the auto-generated class.

Here is the code of my CustomerForm :

```cs
using TestDataModel.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestUI
{
    public partial class CustomerForm : Form
    {

        public CustomerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            custListBox.ClearSelected();
        }

        private void AddNewCustButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            CreateCustomer cc = new CreateCustomer();
            cc.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void CustomerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Test2UEntitiesA db = new Test2UEntitiesA();
            List<Customer> cl = db.Customers.ToList();
            custListBox.DataSource = cl;
            custListBox.DisplayMember ="CustomerName";
            takeNewOrderButton.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customer = (Customer)custListBox.SelectedItem;
            label1.Text = customer.CustomerNumber.ToString();
            label2.Text = customer.CustomerName;
            takeNewOrderButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void TakeNewOrderButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OrderBasketForm ob = new OrderBasketForm((Customer)custListBox.SelectedItem);
            ob.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the order form which uses the customer object

```cs
using TestDataModel.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestUI
{
    public partial class OrderBasketForm : Form
    {
        Customer cust;
        public static OrderBasket ob;
        public OrderBasketForm(Customer customer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cust = customer;
            ob = new OrderBasket();
            Test2UEntitiesA db = new Test2UEntitiesA();
            List<Product> pl = db.Products.ToList();
            label2.Text = cust.CustomerName;
            discValue.Text = cust.Discount.ToString();
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            CustomerForm cf = new CustomerForm();
            cf.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int quantity;
            Product product = (Product)productNameBox.SelectedItem;
            quantity = (int)quantityCounter.Value;

            if (quantity <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No quantity has been selected", "Quantity Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                return; //No items selected
            }

            else
            {
                ob.AddProduct(product.ProductNumber, product.ProductName, product.Price, product.RecommendedRetailPrice, quantity, product.Description);
                BasketItemsToListView();
            }



        }

        public void BasketItemsToListView()
        {
            basketListView.Items.Clear();

            numOfItems.Text = ob.NumberOfItems.ToString();
            numOfProducts.Text = ob.NumberOfProducts.ToString();
            totalBox.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", ob.BasketTotal);
            discTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", ob.BasketTotal);

            //Using ListView Control to display basket contents
            foreach (BasketItem bItem in ob.BasketItems)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[]
                {
                    bItem.ProductNumber.ToString(),
                    bItem.ProductName,
                });

                basketListView.Items.Add(item);
            }

            clearButton.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult clearResponse = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear the basket?", "Clear Basket", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            if (clearResponse == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                ClearBasket();
            }
        }

        private void ClearBasket()
        {
            ob.ClearBasket();
            BasketItemsToListView();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (basketListView.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
                return; //No items selected
            ob.RemoveProduct(Int32.Parse(basketListView.SelectedItems[0].Text));
            BasketItemsToListView();
            removeButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void CheckOutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ob.NumberOfItems == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The basket is currently empty!", "Basket Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                return;
            }

            Test2UEntitiesA db = new Test2UEntitiesA();

            List<OrderItem> itemsToAdd = new List<OrderItem>();

            //create list populate with orderbasket
            foreach (BasketItem item in ob.BasketItems)
            {
                itemsToAdd.Add(new OrderItem
                {
                    ProductNumber = item.ProductNumber,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                });
            }

            //create an order object - needs to match the format of database table
            Order order = new Order
            {
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                CustomerNumber = cust.CustomerNumber,
                CustomerDiscount = cust.Discount,
                OrderStatus = 1,
                OrderTotalBeforeDiscount = ob.BasketTotal,
                OrderItems = itemsToAdd
            };



            //save changes to db
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            OrderHistoryForm ohf = new OrderHistoryForm(cust);
            ohf.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need you to show more Code... You need to reference the Main Project being tested from the Test project, then the `Using` will work.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have added some more code showing the form that creates the customer instance

Comment: @JeremyThompson Apologies for the confusion, TestUI is the main project, this contains all my forms. I know the name is not very god but it does not indicate that this is the test element.

Comment: @HansPassant's comment is probably best. That said, have you tried explicitly referencing your customer... `DataLayerTest.Customer cust;`

Answer (score 0):

If in case you have more than one project in your solution, you can manually add the reference to that project by editing the `.csproj` file and adding this block to it

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

then the using statement will work. Visula studio sometimes runs into an error trying to do this by itself.

But also, you should first try opening the main `.cs file` which you are trying to use but can't find it in the other file, change its namespace and then try referencing it again. Sometimes our naming conventions conflict with .Net namespaces or class libraries which you may have never heard of.